# How to assign RGB color values to grid mesh with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please consider this simplified snippet:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3)
y = np.arange(2)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

I would like to assign already prepared color values to every grid cell.
I have color values of same shape as XY grid for every RGB channel as normalized RGB values - so it's 3 numpy arrays each consisting of 0 to 1 float, representing channel value

I first tried with [matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) as it seems like exact tool for what I want, but I can’t understand how color mapping is done.

It seems that color array (C in documentation) is mapped on default (or assigned manually) colormap, but I can’t get the logic of values in this color array and it’s role.
If values are mapped on default (or assigned) colormap from grid cell value, what is the purpose then of C color array?
I made this C array by hand for above example (2x1 numpy array), but regardless of it values I get same colors that seems dependent only on grid cell value and not values in this C array.

So I’m confused here and ask for kind help, which does not necessarily need to be explanation of this pcolor function, but maybe what is the right way to assign color values to grid mesh with matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `imshow` rather than `pcolor`. (Though you can use `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` for this.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some random data to represent your r, g, b bands.
ny, nx = 2, 3
r, g, b = [np.random.random(ny*nx).reshape((ny, nx)) for _ in range(3)]

c = np.dstack([r,g,b])

plt.imshow(c, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Quite nice! Is that MODIS data? Also, for continuous data, you probably don't want the "nearest" interpolation that I specified in my example.  The default interpolation method is bilinear, and it would be a better fit for your data.

Comment: Thanks again for interpolation tip, image is zoomed with matplotlib and at 1:1 it's beauty of course. And you are right - it seems to me amazing that you figured it only by part of image :) Cheers

Comment: This does not seem to work for `pcolor` and returns the error as `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. Maybe, `pcolor` takes only 1D or 2D arrays as the color arguments. Is there a way to make it work for `pcolor`?